# CGRect Drawing Shapes in XCode (Objective -c)

Tags: cgrect

I just need a help to create a flow diagram by using Core Graphics.
Starting with an yellow elips, and follows by a red diagonal  Shapes, these two shapes are connected by a single head arrow. (shades, colours  and arrows..)
i would be very happy if you could help me
Regards

---

I have created an application for ipad and it has an app delegate file group and 10 other  view controllers.One of those view controllers is "AnimationViewController.xib" and .h and  .m files. 
Now I am going to draw a few shapes on this view (this is separate view).
I dont know whether the applicationDidFinishLaunching method works here or not.
I have applicationDidFinishLaunchingwithOptions in appdelagate .m file.

After launching the application (comes up detail view), I switch to   IfAnimationViewController, and it does not show anything!
I would be very happy if you could help me on this subject.
Many thanks in advance

Btw: I could not submit the codes I have, the system kept asking to put four spaces with using {} button...Its so confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Core Data is the persistency (i.e. database) API, it has nothing to do with drawing.

If you want to draw stuff yourself using primitive quartz operations, you:

- Create a "New File" with your subview of `UIView`
- Implement your own `drawRect:` method, which draws what you want (see below)
- Add an instance of your custom view to the main view (or your window), either when your app launches, or by setting the class of the main view to your custom view in the `.xib` file.

A typical custom `drawRect:` implementation will look something like:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rectToDraw {
  if (CGRectIsNull(rectToDraw))
    return;
  CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx);
  CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
  CGContextFillRect(ctx, rectToDraw);
  UIGraphicsPopContext();
}
```

Your best bet is to start with some of the sample code referenced in [View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html).